What is the range of noon sun color temperature, when a light meter reports full expected sunlight (+/- epsilon)?
My question came from trying to find what uncertainty bounds, if any, I can assign to a color temperature sensor, without access to an artifact with a precisely calibrated output spectrum.
This leads me to ask what bounds I can put on the color temperature of direct sunlight (note: not simply whole-sky light) at midday on a clear day, knowing the nominal atmospheric pathlength from sun elevation angle.
The total solar output outside the atmosphere in recent years is observed by satellites to be steady at the 0.1% level[1], with a spectral distribution having a correlated color temperature (in space) of 5900K [2]. Daylight color temperature on the ground changes with atmospheric absorption and scattering, including by clouds and aerosols. I assume such effects always reduce the net flux coming from within the apparent solar disk, so its total contribution can be constrained by measuring that value as a fraction of the total light from the sky, and the expected full-sun insolation at a given point and time.
A question here [3] has not resolved why the nominal value on the ground is reported at 6500 K. The wiki on standard-illuminant D65 [4] references a 1964 paper by Judd[5] distinguishing measurements of sunlight and (sunlight + skylight) but the free abstract doesn't explain the details.
[1]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant
[2]https://crisp.nus.edu.sg/~research/tutorial/optical.htm
[3]How can daylight have a higher colour temperature (e.g. 6500 K or D65) than sunlight in space?
[4]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_illuminant#Illuminant_series_D
[5]https://opg.optica.org/josa/abstract.cfm?uri=josa-54-8-1031

As an added note, the maximum expected direct solar illumination at sea level with sun at zenith is apparently (1,050 W/m^2) * (93 lumens/ W) = 98000 lux. This is direct sun only, without accounting for the additional skylight incident at other angles from scattering. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight
